# Solution to trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, book-recommendation

While trying to find if a given function is periodic and if so, find its period (later, I proved that it does not have a period - through a different method) I encountered this equation which I was unable to solve (i.e. find the values of $x$ (complex and real) that satisfy it) -
$$ \sin(1)=\sin(1+x)-\sin(\pi x) $$

**My Approach:**
Recently, while going through the Wikipedia article on "Sine", I came across this definition of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ (for all complex $x$)-
$$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

So, I tried using putting these values into the above equation and trying to solve it, but nothing came of it.

====================================================

Now, I learnt - through other questions on this site - that such an equation does not necessarily have an algebraic solution; but I was unable to find a question (or any such material elsewhere on the net) that gives a method to solve such equations -
$$ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n {a_i(\sin(k_ix))^{p_i}}=0$$

Where $a_i, k_i, p_i$ take all real values.

Using the above mentioned substitutions, the above should become equivalent to solving -

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n{m_ie^{t_ix}}=0$$
Where $m_i, t_i$ can take all complex values.

So, my question is - How would one go about solving equations of the above kind in general (or - is there no general method?).

Also, what good book (meaning easy to understand, widely used and having an in-depth coverage of the topic) at an undergraduate level (I'm in the last year of high school) would cover the above kind of equations?

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, book recommendations  are actually allowed on the site, as by the book-recommendation tag